# How to send apk file in chat Like HIKE?

Tags: android

I am making Chat Application like WhatsApp and I want to add **.apk** file attachment in my Application.

So how to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the apk file,

> Here is the snippt code:
>
> ```
> final Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
> mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
> final List pkgAppsList = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, 0);
> for (Object object : pkgAppsList) {
>     ResolveInfo info = (ResolveInfo) object;
>     File file = new File(info.activityInfo.applicationInfo.publicSourceDir);
>     // Copy the .apk file to wherever
> }
> ```

After this you can send the apk as a file to another device.

To send the files via socket,
[Go through this small example](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0542.html)

Comment: Please update this answer with how to "send the `File`" object. As it stands, this is purely a copied answer.

Comment: Sorry for this, but the question clearly states **_how to add .apk file attachment_**. My answer clearly states how to get the apk file, to make things easier! I've also included a link to help with sending the file.

Comment: thanks guys its work ..

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted if it helped..